# Saving Serializable Objects List into sharedPreferences

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me how I can save a list of custom  `Serializable` objects into `SharedPreference`? I am new To Android and I want to save an `ArrayList<Contact> list` into shared preferences.

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
PlaceSlidesFragmentAdapter mAdapter;
ViewPager mPager;
PageIndicator mIndicator;

public static final String TAG = "detailsFragment";

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main,
            container, false);

    mAdapter = new PlaceSlidesFragmentAdapter(getActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) view.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    ((CirclePageIndicator) mIndicator).setSnap(true);

    mIndicator
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getActivity(),
                            "Changed to page " + position,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position,
                        float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                }
            });
    return view;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the **JSON** format to serialize your `ArrayList` and the objects it contains, and then store the `String` result into the `SharedPreferences`.

When you want to get the data back, retrieve the String and use a `JSONArray` to retrieve each object and add it to a new ArrayList.

Otherwise you can simply use `Object(Input/Output)Stream` classes and write it into a differente file using (for writing)

```
FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
final OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

// Add your objects to the array

osw.write(array.toString());
osw.flush();
osw.close();
```

Answer (score 33):

Another good solution is to use GSON. Here's an example:

```
private static final String MAP = "map";    
private static final Type MAP_TYPE = new TypeToken<Map<MyObjA, MyObjB>>() {}.getType();

private static SharedPreferences prefs = MyApplication.getContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

private static Map<MyObjA, MyObjB> myMap;

public static void saveMap (Map<MyObjA, MyObjB> map) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    editor.putString(MAP, new Gson().toJson(map));
    editor.commit();
    myMap = map;
}

public static Map<MyObjA, MyObjB> loadMap() {
    if (myMap == null) {
        myMap = new Gson().fromJson(prefs.getString(MAP, null), MAP_TYPE);
    }
    return myMap;
}
```

More information about gson at http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ 
Pretty simple right? ;)
Take care

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way out?

Convert to `JSON` and save it as a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

If it's already serialized, then you can just put it in. the accepted answer in this post will point you in the direction: [Save ArrayList to SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences)

Answer (score 0):

try this, works for me :

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

**DataList.java :**

```
import java.util.List;

public class DataList {
    List<Data> dataList;

    public List<Data> getDataList() {
        return dataList;
    }

    public void setDataList(List<Data> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java :**

```
    List<Data> fetchLog = new ArrayList<Data>();
    DataList dataList = null;


    dataList = new DataList();
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    //SAVE List As SharedPreferences
    Data data = new Data("ali",20);
    fetchLog.add(data);
    dataList.setDataList(fetchLog);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(dataList);
    
    utils.setPref("logs", json);// function to set SharedPreferences


    // read List from SharedPreferences
        String json = utils.getPref("logs");// function to read SharedPreferences
        if (! json.equals("")) {
            dataList = gson.fromJson(json, DataList.class);
            fetchLog = dataList.getDataList();
        }
```